# C3.js x-axis show every other categories

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, c3.js

in my data, I have:
data = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, ...., d100]; (d1-d100 are int or float)
labels = [v1, v2, v3, ..., v100]; (v1 - v100 are strings, categories in C3.js)

Because there are 100 labels and hard to show all of them on x-axis, I only want to show every 5th or every 10th.

If labels are integer, I can use culling in ticks;
If labels are time, I can use count in ticks;
But I didn't see any solution for categories.

I tried to make invisible label as an empty string "", but in the C3 graph, the visible labels cannot show correctly, since empty strings takes space in the graph, even they are empty.

I did the same thing in D3.js. But I don't want to use d3.js because some other feature in C3.js is better.

Any better solution?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `axis.x.tick.culling.max`?

```
tick: {
    culling: {
        max: 2 // or whatever value you need
    }
```

If you wanted every 5th tick to show and had 100 ticks in total, you'd set the value of `max` to be equal to `100/5`, i.e. `20`.

Here's a basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln83xd1k/4/

## EDIT

To get the x-axis label to NOT wrap onto multiple lines when there isn't enough space, try adding `axis.x.tick.multiline = false`, like so:

```
axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['long category name goes here', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx', 'catx'],
            tick: {
                multiline:false,
                culling: {
                    max:2
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't help. I also tried .count, and it doesn't work. What I have is a list of strings. And the strings are dates, but not a single date. It looks like "2015-01-12-2015-02-01". I don't want to show it vertically. Event I use a function to show every 5 string, the ones don't show still take places, which make the shown one has to be vertical. Also see your example, "cat1" and "catx" are vertical and x in catx almost covered.

Comment: If you change the 13th value to "catxxxxxxxxxx", it only shows "catx" in the graph. C3.js makes things easier but harder to change it.